# How to define a explicit constructor when the parent class doesn't have a default constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

I'm getting the following error in my code:

> Implicit super constructor GLabel() is undefined for default
>   constructor. Must define an explicit constructor

My parent class "GLabel" is contained in an external jar.  I can open the source file, but I can't make edits to it.  So I decided to extend GLabel to create the functionality I want.

As you can see "GLabel" class does not have an empty constructor.  I'm assuming this is what is causing the issue?  How do I fix this?

**Child Class**

```
import acm.graphics.GLabel;

public class BreakoutLabels extends GLabel{

    // no code inside

}
```

**Parent Class**

```
public class GLabel extends GObject {

    public static final Font DEFAULT_FONT = new Font("Default", 0, 12);

    private String label;

    private Font labelFont;

    public GLabel(String str) {
        this(str, 0.0D, 0.0D);
    }

    public GLabel(String str, double x, double y) {
        label = str;
        setFont(DEFAULT_FONT);
        setLocation(x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Define a constructor that calls the super class constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `GLabel` *doesn't* have a default (empty-args) constructor, then your constructors for your derived class *have* to call one of the declared constructors for `GLabel`. However `GLabel` is defined means that a default constructor makes no sense, and you'll have to provide suitable arguments.